# is compactness equivalent to limit point compactness?

Tags: general-topology, compactness

I would like to know if compactness is equivalent to limit point compactness in general for any topology. If so I'd like to see a proof, other wise I'd like to see a counter example. I am curious about this because I want to get an intuition for compactness, limit point compactness makes intuitive sense to me as a way of determining if you can "escape" the space by getting ever closer to a point "outside" the space, however the idea of open covers and open sub covers seem to come out of no where, I'd like to see an example where there 2 definitions differ so that hopefully I can see the need for the compactness definition that we use.

This is not a duplicate of limit point compactness implies compactness as I am not just asking about the first direction of implication but rather both directions of implication, I also want to know if compactness implies limit point compactness.

Comment: That sounds suspiciously like a homework question. Why are you interested in that specific question?

Comment: a) Could you include the question in the body of the question? And b) please follow the guidelines outlined by [How to ask a good question?](http://goo.gl/PlJyVQ) and [How to ask a homework question?](https://goo.gl/Fyfb22). Low quality questions (which do not adhere to the above guidelines) run the risk of being [closed](https://goo.gl/J58Qwn) and [deleted](https://goo.gl/FmJes1), and repeated closures and deletions may trigger a [question ban](https://goo.gl/7QcTa9).

Comment: I'm curious as to the difference between the 2 definitions

Comment: What is your exact definition of limit point compactness?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $\tau$ be a topology on ${\bf{N}}$ generated by $\{1,2\},\{3,4\},\{5,6\},...$

$\tau$ is limit point compact.

$\tau$ is not compact by considering the open cover $\{\{1,2\},\{3,4\},\{5,6\},...\}$.

A proof that $\tau$ is limit point compact. Say, an infinite set $A$. If $A$ contains an even number $k$, then we claim that $k-1$ is a limit point for $A$: The basic open set $\{k-1,k\}$ contains $k$, and $\{k-1,k\}-\{k\}\cap A=\{k-1\}\cap A=\{k-1\}\ne\emptyset$.

Similarly, if $A$ contains a odd number $l$, then $l+1$ is a limit point for $A$.

Answer (score 0):

No they are not the same. A typical example is to take an uncountable product
Eg $$\{0,1\}^{[0,1]}$$ which is compact but contains a sequence with no convergent subsequence.

Comment: could you give such a sequence?

Comment: Divide the interval $[0,1]$ into $2^n$ many intervals, and alternate $0$ and $1$ on these intervals.